# should .angular be in gitignore

Tags: angular, angular14upgrade

I recently upgraded Angular from v12 to v14 using the `ng update` command and did the required modifications manually.
The command added a `.angular` folder with a cache library that seems huge:

[image]

But it didn't add the cache folder to `.gitignore`.

Should I add `.angular` to my `.gitignore`?

Comment: `/.angular/cache` should be ignored, looks like that got [done for me](https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/commit/f3a60105b7070585a9eaf5ebe83b6268f572cf62) in the 12-13 migration, did you skip a step?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, after researching and repeating the process, the answer is yes, `/.angular/cache` should be added to `.gitignore` in Angular 14.

Comment: FYI `/.angular/cache` got auto added to `.gitignore` when I ran `ng update` - I don't remember which ng versions I was upgrading from and to